# How to get from requestId for GetResponseBodyAsync in DevTool CEFSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Tell me how to get text from requests via GetResponseBodyAsync ()

I need to check for the text in the request, as soon as there is the desired text, write it to a variable and close the browser

http://cefsharp.github.io/api/87.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_DevTools_Network_NetworkClient_GetResponseBodyAsync.htm

https://cefsharp.github.io/api/87.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_IBrowser_Identifier.htm

Comment: The DevTools protocol has an online API viewer available at https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/ the GetResponseBodyAsync method maps to https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBody Looking at the DevTools protocol,  I'm guessing you call enable (EnableAsync) and get the RequestId from the responseReceived or loadingFinished events, not sure which exactly. You'll have to do some testing. Alternatively use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/87.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_GetSourceAsync.htm

Comment: I still cannot get the server response body, I use
             var client = browser.GetDevToolsClient ();

            
             client.Network.EnableAsync ();

But I don't have
Network.RequestId
I have no choice of RequestId

I am using CefSharp.OffScreen

I would be very grateful for a sample code or a link to a sample code

Comment: No such example exists and I've never tried to implement what you are trying. I'd suggest using GetSourceAsync. Have you considered using headless chrome with puppateer Sharp?